# Deciding if all intervals are overlapping

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, optimization, intervals

I'm doing a problem that n people is standing on a line and each person knows their own position and speed. I'm asked to find the minimal time to have all people go to any spot.

Basically what I'm doing is finding the minimal time using binary search and have every ith person's furthest distance to go in that time in intervals. If all intervals overlap, there is a spot that everyone can go to.

I have a solution to this question but the time limit exceeded for it for my bad solution to find the intervals. My current solution runs too slow and I'm hoping to get a better solution.

my code:

```
    people = int(input())
    peoplel = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(people)] # first item in people[i] is the position of each person, the second item is the speed of each person
    def good(time):
        return checkoverlap([[i[0] - time *i[1], i[0] + time * i[1]] for i in peoplel])
        # first item,second item = the range of distance a person can go to 
 

    def checkoverlap(l):
        for i in range(len(l) - 1):
            seg1 = l[i]
            for i1 in range(i + 1, len(l)):
                seg2 = l[i1]
                if seg2[0] <= seg1[0] <= seg2[1] or seg1[0] <= seg2[0] <= seg1[1]:
                    continue
                elif seg2[0] <= seg1[1] <= seg2[1] or seg1[0] <= seg2[1] <= seg1[1]:
                    continue
                return False
        return True
```

(this is my first time asking a question so please inform me about anything that is wrong)

Comment: What if everyone arrives at the spot at different times?

Comment: @btilly Sorry for not being clear enough, the interval is the range of distance a person can go to during that time, the time is the minimal time for everyone to arrive at that spot. So, if all intervals overlap, everyone can go to that spot after walking x time, then I just search the minimal time that everyone can go to that spot.

Comment: I would recommend trying to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm for this.  Your linear inequalities are that everyone can get to a point and time.  You're trying to optimize time.

Comment: Why so complicated? It seems more like a task for an algorithm. The LP might be a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### One does simply go linear

A while after I finished the answer I found a simplification that removes the need for sorting and thus allows us to further reduce the complexity of finding if all the intervals are overlapping to **O(N)**.

If we look at the steps that are being done after the initial sort we can see that we are basically checking

```
if max(lower_bounds) < min(upper_bounds):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

And since both `min` and `max` are linear without the need for sorting, we can simplify the algorithm by:

- Creating an array of lower bounds - one pass.
- Creating an array of upper bounds - one pass.
- Doing the comparison I mentioned above - two passes over the new arrays.

All this could be done together in one one pass to further optimize(and to prevent some unnecessary memory allocation), however this is clearer for the explanation's purpose.

Since the reasoning about the correctness and timing was done in the previous iteration, I will skip it this time and keep the section below since it nicely shows the thought process behind the optimization.

### One sort to rule them all

**Disclaimer:** This section was obsoleted time-wise by the one above. However since it in fact allowed me to figure out the linear solution, I'm keeping it here.

As the title says, sorting is a rather straightforward way of going about this. It will require a little different data structure - instead of holding every interval as `(min, max)` I opted for holding every interval as `(min, index), (max, index)`.
This allows me to sort these by the `min` and `max` values. What follows is a single linear pass over the sorted array. We also create a helper array of False values. These represent the fact that at the beginning all the intervals are closed.
Now comes the pass over the array:

- Since the array is sorted, we first encounter the `min` of each interval. In such case, we increase the `openInterval` counter and a `True` value of the interval itself. Interval is now open - until we close the interval, the person can arrive at the party - we are within his(or her) range.
- We go along the array. As long as we are opening the intervals, everything is ok and if we manage to open all the intervals, we have our party destination where all the social distancing collapses. If this happens, we return **True**.
- If we close any of the intervals, we have found our party breaker who can't make it anymore. (Or we can discuss that the party breakers are those who didn't bother to arrive yet when someone has to go already). We return **False**.

The resulting complexity is **O(Nlog(N))** caused by the initial sort since the pass itself is linear in nature. This is quite a bit better than the original O(n^2) caused by the "check all intervals pairwise" approach.

#### The code:

```
import numpy as np
import cProfile, pstats, io

#random data for a speed test. Not that useful for checking the correctness though.
testSize = 10000
x = np.random.randint(0, 10000, testSize)
y = np.random.randint(1, 100, testSize)
peopleTest = [x for x in zip(x, y)]

#Just a basic example to help with the reasoning about the correctness
peoplel = [(1, 2), (3, 1), (8, 1)]
# first item in people[i] is the position of each person, the second item is the speed of each person


def checkIntervals(people, time):
    a = [(x[0] - x[1] * time, idx) for idx, x in enumerate(people)]
    b = [(x[0] + x[1] * time, idx) for idx, x in enumerate(people)]
    checks = [False for x in range(len(people))]
    openCount = 0
    intervals = [x for x in sorted(a + b, key=lambda x: x[0])]
    for i in intervals:
        if not checks[i[1]]:
            checks[i[1]] = True
            openCount += 1
            if openCount == len(people):
                return True
        else:
            return False

    print(intervals)



def good(time, people):
    return checkoverlap([[i[0] - time * i[1], i[0] + time * i[1]] for i in people])
    # first item,second item = the range of distance a person can go to


def checkoverlap(l):
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        seg1 = l[i]
        for i1 in range(i + 1, len(l)):
            seg2 = l[i1]
            if seg2[0] <= seg1[0] <= seg2[1] or seg1[0] <= seg2[0] <= seg1[1]:
                continue
            elif seg2[0] <= seg1[1] <= seg2[1] or seg1[0] <= seg2[1] <= seg1[1]:
                continue
            return False
    return True


pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

print(checkIntervals(peopleTest, 10000))

print(good(10000, peopleTest))

pr.disable()
s = io.StringIO()
sortby = "cumulative"
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print(s.getvalue())
```

#### The profiling stats for the pass over test array with 10K random values:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.001    0.001    8.933    8.933 (good)
    1    8.925    8.925    8.926    8.926 (checkoverlap)
    1    0.003    0.003    0.023    0.023 (checkIntervals)
    1    0.008    0.008    0.010    0.010 {built-in method builtins.sorted}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is way faster than my brute force approach to this problem. Didn't think of this way to solve it.